# Why "ping" is so big despite vast speed transmission?

Tags: networking, ping

"Ping" measures response delay of any host. And it use ICMP protocol and Network card should process it at hardware low level.

Why "ping" to some host is measured by 50 - 100 milliseconds, if speed internet of downloading file using TCP to same host is > 10 MiB.

If "ping" > 100 ms, then <10 packets per second can be transferred, and internet speed using TCP should be < 10 KiB.

Is "Ping" the logarithmic measurement ?

"Ping" should be less than 1 milli-second

Comment: TCP can adjust the window size and transmit at high speeds despite higher pings. Other than that bandwidth has little to do with latency.

Comment: ICMP is a low-priority protocol. Devices will first do what they were designed to do, then when the device has time, it will deal with ICMP. Ping is not meant to be a measurement tool, it is designed to report network reachability. The time is really an afterthought, and it is not meant to be a precise measurement.

Comment: Thank you.I connected two PCs and ping is 1 ms. Probably "ping" command < 1ms round to 1 ms.